# Как лучше реализовать распределение ролей и прав?

Tags: php, yii2, безопасность, rbac

Разрабатываю сервис на Yii2, на котором необходимо разделять роли и права у пользователей.

Пытаюсь реализовать `rbac`. Где то делаю проверки на роль, где то на пермишен.

Пока есть 4 роли: админ, модер, юзер. У каждой роли свои права. И у одной роли смешанные права: т.е. все права юзера + n прав модера. Таких ролей может стать больше.

Не хочется преждевременной оптимизации, но смотреть в завтрашний день всегда полезно.

Как лучше реализовать доступ к правам в фильтрах `AccessControl`:

1. Делать проверку на соответствие роли пользователя определенной роли (`can('user')`)(тогда придется напрячься для разработки логики доступа каждой из смешанных ролей)
2. Делать проверку на permissions (`can('viewItem'),can('updateItem'), can('deleteItemImage'), can('updateName')`)(как по мне лучший вариант, т.к. больше вариативности)
3. Делать проверку на группы ролей (группа->роль->пермишен) (тоже неплохо, но тогда есть возможность образования множества маленьких груп по 1-2 роли внизу)

Comment: Так а наследовать же можно. Админ наследует модера и юзера, модер наследует юзера и т.д.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, да, я это и реализовал. но что если мне понадобится дать пользователю право выше и заблокировать право ниже? тогда придется блокировать всю роль. как быть тогда?

Comment: @fedornabilkin, из этого и вытекают проблемы 1-го и 3-го варианта: негибкость создания новых ролей и бесконечное создание новых групп.

Comment: Подход rbac не предполагает блокировку прав. По умолчанию заблокировано все. Если понадобится право выше без низшего, что мешает создать еще одну роль? Если к роли добавлять описание, тогда путаница не возникнет. Обычно, если кто-то обладает высокими правами, автоматом обладает и более низкими. В другом случае эти права находятся на одном уровне (право 1 ИЛИ право 2).

Comment: @fedornabilkin, извините что ввел в заблуждение, поправил вопрос. я понимаю как работает система прав в rbac, я не понимаю как осуществлять проверку доступа: проверять на роль, перишен или проверять на группу?

Comment: Насколько я помню, надо проверять на пермишен, потому что к каждой роли добавляются пермишены или другая роль со всеми своими пермишенами. Но этот функционал уже реализован в mdmsoft/yii2-admin, можно подсмотреть.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, вот поэтому я и спрашиваю, как лучше. то есть вы предлагаете для каждого экшена проверять соответствующий пермишен, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону компонента https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin
На нашем ресурсе он нас устраивает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать модуль https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-rbac.

Здесь permission - это путь к action. Модуль предоставляет готовые контроллеры для управления ролями.

Сначала заходим в маршруты (/rbac/route/index) и выбираем маршруты которые будут использоваться для настройки прав - по сути формируем пермишены, которые затем будем назначать на роли (перетягиваем маршруты из левого списка в правый).

Затем создаем роли (/rbac/role/index) и в каждой указываем какие пути этой роли доступны. Модуль автоматически будет проверять есть ли права на выполнение action у текущего пользователя (в конфиге приложения добавляем поведение для проверки доступа ко всем actions - параметр 'as access').

Можно дополнительно проверять доступ и так `Yii::$app->routeAccess->can('/post/create')`.
Например делать неактивными кнопки:

```
<?= Html::a(
    'label', 
    ['/post/create'],
    ['class'=>'btn btn-primary' . (Yii::$app->routeAccess->can('/post/create') ? '' : ' disabled')]) 
?>
```

Если появляется роль в которой нужно что-то запретить, то разбиваем уже используемую роль на базовую (без каких-то определенных прав) и продвинутую. Скажем, у нас был модератор. Теперь нам нужен модератор, но который не может удалять посты. Тогда делаем:

- Модератор базовый
- Модератор с удалением (наследует Модератор базовый + дополнительные маршруты)

Comment: так это же проверка каждого пермишена в обертке проверки путей, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да, это по сути проверка пермишена. просто количество пермишенов со временем наростает и становится проще проверять пути

Comment: ну да, действительно. я уже пользуюсь этим расширением для назначения пермишенов через интерфейс и не понимаю как проверять пути: есть адрес `/route` где просто отображаются все доступные пути. как их проверить?

Comment: не совсем понял вопрос

Comment: сейчас я использую это расширение чтобы назначать ролям пермишены через интерфейс, роут `/rbac`. а как пользоваться роутом `/rbac/route` (если это то, о чем вы написали в ответе) я не понимаю. как этим пользоваться?

Comment: На странице `/rbac/route/index` формируем в правой колонке список путей, которые будут использоваться, т.е. попадут в пермишены. Потом на /rbac/role/index заходим в роль и накидываем из этого списка пути которые будут доступны этой роли. Далее нужно добавить yii2mod\rbac\filters\AccessControl::class либо в настройках конфига приложения в `as access` либо прямо в контролере в `behaviors`.

Comment: ааа, вон оно что! а я все понять не могу, зачем мне перетягивать маршруты из левой колонки в правую и что с ними дальше делать! спасибо!